# incompatible type in assignement

Tags: c, incomplete-type

i'm trying to shuffle a set of arrays and print them in the shuffled order, but i get the `error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'int' from type 'IRIS'` and i can't overcome it.

I'm a beginner programmer (just learned some basic C over past week for a university exam).

this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_SAMPLES 5
#define OUTPUT 3
typedef struct {
  double sepal_lenght;
  double sepal_width;
  double petal_lenght;
  double petal_width;
  double out[OUTPUT];
}IRIS;
IRIS samples[MAX_SAMPLES] = {
{5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,{0.0,1.0,0.0}},
{6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,{1.0,0.0,0.0}},
{6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,{1.0,0.0,0.0}},
{7.6,3.0,6.6,2.1,{1.0,0.0,0.0}},
{7.7,2.8,6.7,2.0,{1.0,0.0,0.0}},
};
main (){
int i, temp, randomIndex;
srand(time(NULL));
  for ( i=1; i < MAX_SAMPLES; i++) {
   temp = samples[i];
   randomIndex = rand() %MAX_SAMPLES;
   samples[i] = samples[randomIndex];
   samples[randomIndex] = temp;
}
for ( i=0; i<MAX_SAMPLES; i++) {
  printf("%d\n", samples[i]);
}
}
```

error in line: `temp = samples[i];`

any help very appriciated!

Comment: You assign an `int` to a `IRIS`, which are incompatible types. That's everything.

Comment: `temp` is of type `int`; `samples[i]` is of type `IRIS`

Comment: `lenght` should be `length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `temp` from the list of `int`s before the loop, then change this:

```
temp = samples[i];
```

to:

```
const IRIS temp = samples[i];
```

You can't assign a value of type `IRIS` to an `int`.

Comment: thank you very much! this solved it! (and i learned something new)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an IRIS type array but in your for loop you are using %d which are used for displaying only int into printf.
If you want to display data from your structure IRIS, you must access the attribute you want to display, not the structure itself.
For example:

```
printf("%f\n", samples[i].sepal_lenght);
```

Comment: thank you very much! your suggestion was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Your `temp` is of type `int` while `samples` is an array of `IRIS`, so you need `temp` to be `IRIS` and then copy all the contents of `samples[i]` into it.